# Output the results of select operation in an array - jq

Tags: bash, jq

I have the following input:

```
[
  {"id": "first", "val": 1}, 
  {"id": "second", "val": 2}, 
  {"id": "second", "val": 3}
]
```

Using the jq filter : .[] | select(.id == "second")

I get following as output :

```
 {
  "id": "second",
  "val": 2
 }
 {
  "id": "second",
  "val": 3
 }
```

I want to get the result in the form of an array. Is it possible to get the multiple result values of select operation in an array?

Comment: Please clarify the requirements by giving further details about what you expect the exact result to be in the example.

Answer (score 83):

Yes; wrap the filter in an array :)

```
$ jq '[.[] | select(.id == "second")]' tmp.json
[
  {
    "id": "second",
    "val": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "second",
    "val": 3
  }
]
```

Or, use `map/1`, which is predefined as `[.[] | ...]`.

```
$ jq 'map(select(.id == "second"))' tmp.json
[same result]
```

---

To wrap the results in a `bash` array, use the `-c` option to output each result on a single line, and read the result with `readarray`.

```
$ readarray -t arr < <(jq -c '.[] | select(.id == "second")' tmp.json)
$ for r in "${arr[@]}"; do echo "Result: $r"; done
Result: {"id":"second","val":2}
Result: {"id":"second","val":3}
```

Comment: I am using bash script. I tried the above approach but I am not able to traverse the array. `out=$(echo $inp | jq 'map(select(.id == "second"))')`

Comment: Oh, you want a `bash` array, not a JSON array?

Comment: echo ${#out[@]} returns 1

Comment: amazing @chepner, I 've been messing around with that for the whole day.