# Why my simple list to array transform isn't working in jq?

Tags: json, jq

I'm having an hard time trying to grok jq for good.
I want to change the result from list to array. Now this question was already addressed on these SO questions that say to just put brackets arount the query:

[Output the results of select operation in an array - jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302617/output-the-results-of-select-operation-in-an-array-jq)

[JQ: How to turn output of array selector back into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63801953/jq-how-to-turn-output-of-array-selector-back-into-an-array)

What I want is basically the same but it's not working. I have a file with three lines:

```
me 
you
them
```

now with this command line: `cat list | jq -R '.'` The result is:

```
"me"
"you"
"them"
```

ok now I want to convert to array, so as in the questions I should only put some brackets in the identity filter. If I do this (`cat list | jq -R '[.]'`) I get:

```
[
  "me"
]
[
  "you"
]
[
  "them"
]
```

??? WHYYYY ? If I try `cat list | jq -R '.[]'` the result is:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot iterate over string ("me")
jq: error (at <stdin>:2): Cannot iterate over string ("you")
jq: error (at <stdin>:3): Cannot iterate over string ("them")
```

how do I get

```
[
    "me",
    "you",
    "them"
]
```

? I don't want to use `inputs` function. I want to be able to use in the simple `cat whatever | jq 'whatever'` format.
The worst thing is that it works for a complex query on a big JSON but not for that simple case. What am I doing wrong ?

**Edit**

I found a way to do it, but I don't consider this an answer because I really think there should be a better way, please enlighten me on how I could do this better.

```
cat list | jq -sR 'split("\n") | map(select(length > 0))'
```

then I finally got the desired

```
[
    "me",
    "you",
    "them"
]
```

without map I got another (empty) string in the array due to the last \n

Ugly as hell and I still don't know why I got the results I mentioned above. To me `cat list | jq -R '[.]')` should have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you arrived at is valid, but this is an explanation of why it works and why the other attempts did not:

#### Why does `cat list | jq -R '[.]'` not work?

Because `jq` isn't running the filter once, but once for **each line** of input. In other words, the `.` is only ever one of the 3 inputs by itself; so `[.]` turns that single element into an array, and then having run 3 times, you have 3 arrays.

You are expecting `-R` to quote each string, and each string gets quoted separately because `jq` is reading each line and running the filter on it (the default unless you provide the `-s`), but then on which run of the filter would we create the array? Therefore, the 3 arrays.

#### Why does `cat list | jq -sR ' ... '` work?

Because now, we told `jq` to treat the entire input across multiple lines as one string. So, the `-R` quotes the entire input making it a valid JSON type (a string), which you then split to produce an array and remove the extraneous empty element.

#### Why does `cat list | jq -s '.'` work if the file has only numbers?

This might be surprising, but consider either of these two commands that produce the numbers separated by newlines and spaces respectively:

```bash
§ seq 1 3 | jq -s '.'
§ echo 1 2 3 | jq -s '.'
```

Both will produce this output:

```json
[
  1,
  2,
  3
]
```

The reason this works is because each `1`, `2`, and `3` are each valid JSON, and `jq` can put them in an array to be passed to the filter.

And now consider this (it will work the same way when each element is on its own line, but each element must be a valid JSON by itself) and notice the array around results:

```
§ echo '1 2 3 [1, 2,3] "man" { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }'  | jq -s '.'
[
  1,
  2,
  3,
  [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "man",
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  }
]
```

And now notice the line below where it has an issue on (i.e., after encountering an unquoted `d`). Also, notice that `false` and `true` were just fine as they are valid boolean constants in JSON. So, we can infer that when it encounters an unquoted token, the parser assumes that it is reading a number, hence the error message about "invalid numeric literal":

```bash
§ cat -n list
     1  [1, 2, 3] 
     2  "a" 
     3  false
     4  "b" 
     5  true
     6  "c"
     7  d
     8  "e"

§ cat list | jq -s '.'
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 8, column 0
```

#### Why does `cat list | jq -R | jq -s '.'` work?

Running the `jq -R` quotes the strings, and so we are basically doing:

```
§ cat list 
"me" 
"you" 
"them"

§ cat list | jq -s '.'
[
  "me",
  "you",
  "them"
]
```

Comment: Very good answer thanks. Now I understand much better, but there are still some points that aren't clear enough to me. But I think it's better to open another question about them. I'll link it here ASA it's ready. Again thanks.

Comment: As I was writting the question, I reflected about the things you said, read more of the documentation and I think it's finally clear to me why things work the way they work. I won't need the other question. One more time thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The succinct solution is the one you disallow:

```
jq -Rn '[inputs]'
```

Next best without using `split` would be:

```
jq -R . list | jq -s .
```

Depending on which version of jq you use, you might also be able to use a variant such as:

```
 cat list | jq -R | jq -s
```

Comment: In all of them I got `"me\nyou\nthem\n"`

Comment: Please see updates.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem comes in with `jq` trying to parse the input as JSON on some level (even though -R is being passed)

If the input can be quoted, `jq` does output it correctly with a simple filter, i.e

```
awk '{print "\""$0"\""}' list  | jq -s '.'
```

or

```
cat list | jq -R '.' | jq -s '.'
```

both work given the original input.

The following works, provided you can quote the inputs e.g

```
"me"
"you"
"them"
```

```
cat list2 | jq -s '.'
```

returns:

```
[
  "me",
  "you",
  "them"
]
```

Comment: With jq things only get more strange, the deeper I go. LOL. Why would `jq -R '.' | jq -s '.'` work different than `'jq -Rs '.'` ? this is really strange. Also how do I convert a result output list to an array again ? why `cat list | jq -R '[.]'` doesn't work ?

Comment: It's order of execution and type of data when each is running which makes the difference. The simplest way of doing this would be `jq -n -R  '[ inputs ]' list` which was disallowed by the original question. Because `input` can't be used you have to jump through the additional hoop.